# Python version of h=area() in Matlab

Tags: python

I asked a related question yesterday and fortunately got my answer from jlarsch quickly.  But now I am stuck with the next part, which starts with the `h=area()` line.  I'd like to know the python version of the `area()` function, via which I will be able to set the colors.  Could someone shed me some light again?  Thanks much in advance.

```
...
    Subplot (2,1,1);
    H = plot (rand(100,5));
    C = get (H, 'Color')
    H = area (myX, myY);
    H(1).FaceColor = C(1);
    H(2).FaceColor = C(2);
    Grid on;
...
```

Comment: Please submit your complete code and ask a clear concise question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pretty much exact equivalent of MATLAB's [Area plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html) is matplotlib's [stackplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot).  Here is the first MATLAB example from the above link reproduced using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(4)
y = [[1, 3, 1, 2],
     [5, 2, 5, 6],
     [3, 7, 3, 1]]
plt.stackplot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

And here is the result:

[image: Stack plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone, for all the tips.  I will use stackplot as TheBlackCat suggested.  Indeed it's a closest match to area() in matlab.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [pygame.draw.polygon()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html), which can fill a polygon defined by an arbitrary array of points.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `plt.fill()`.
A huge amount of graph types at [Matplotlib Gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html)